# Django FreedTDS: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist

Tags: python, django, pyodbc, django-settings

I'm trying to connect Django 3.0 with sql_server.pyodbc but I have next error: `jango.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (20009) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

My DATABASES settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': '....',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': '....',
        'HOST': '....',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
           'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'
         }
    }
}
```

Can you help me to find the bug, please? 
Is there another way to connect django wiht SQL Server?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your configuration because you are specifying Microsoft's "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server" in your DATABASES settings but you are getting a FreeTDS error message. Microsoft's ODBC driver (msodbcsql) and FreeTDS ODBC (tdsodbc) are two completely separate ODBC drivers.

Comment: @GordThompson You're right, I had a mistake in **odbcinst.ini** file. I changed `Driver=/usr/local/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.5.2.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib` and it was solved. Thank you.